# WCF Unsecured response in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soap

I'm working on client application to utilize SOAP web service. Added SOAP web services as Service reference. It connects to IBM server and server requires WS-Security basic authentification.

Called with default settings and got an error(no authentication header)

Modified code to look like so:

```
    var service = new RealTimeOnlineClient();
    service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxxxx";
    service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "yyyyy";
```

Now when I look at response in Fiddler - works properly (I get expected envelope from server), I get proper envelope back.

However, I get exception from WCF:

`Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security.`

Quick search and bunch of answers here on SO points me to HotFix from Microsoft where they added new property `EnableUnsecuredResponse`. Problem is - I can't figure out WHERE to apply this property in my code OR in config. Adding to `security` tag in web.config doesn't work (errors out can't find property).

I understand hotfix came out for .NET 3.5 and most questions from 2009-2010. It should be in 4.5 already, correct? How do I apply this property to my code?

Comment: why didn't you add this to your config file `<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" enableUnsecuredResponse="true">`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to add following code to alter value of "EnableUnsecureResponse"

```
var service = new RealTimeOnlineClient();
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxxxx";
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "yyyyy";

var elements = service.Endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();
elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>().EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
service.Endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding(elements);
```

Comment: Did you ever find a way to declare this setting administrative via the configuration file?